# Sorcery Gem - Custom user_info_mapping for external providers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, sorcery

I am using version 0.7.7 of the [Sorcery Authentication Gem](https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery) by NoamB on my `Rails 3.2 App`

I am looking for a possibility how i can hook up a method which is doing the user info mapping for a specific `external login provider (e.g. facebook, twitter)`.

For example I want to change the provided locale to the format I use in my database or I want to download the user avatar from twitter as part of the matching process.

By default it is only possible this way over the `sorcery.rb` file:

```
config.facebook.user_info_mapping = {:email => "email", :first_name => "first_name", :last_name => "last_name" ...
```

I know I can achieve such behavior with setter methods on my user model but I want to keep these things separate from the model and I want to be able to define them specifically for each provider.

Is this possible?
/
What is the best way to implement such extended mapping options?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could do this by extending the various Sorcery provider classes to add the application-specific fields you want to the user info hash.

For example, to use Twitter you might have something like this defined:

```
config.external_providers = [:twitter]
```

You could change this to:

```
config.external_providers = [:TwitterWithAvatar]
```

Now you need to define the `TwitterWithAvatar` provider under `Sorcery::Providers`, and override the `#get_user_hash` method:

```
module Sorcery
  module Providers
    class TwitterWithAvatar < Twitter
      def get_user_hash(access_token)
        user_hash = super
        user_hash.merge(
          avatar: get_avatar(user_hash[:uid]),
        )
      end

      private

      def get_avatar(uid)
        # Some Twitter API call
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you could set up your mapping:

```
config.TwitterWithAvatar.user_info_mapping = {avatar: "avatar"}
```

Alternatively, since you're already using a custom provider class, you could move your mapping into that class:

```
module Sorcery
  module Providers
    class TwitterWithAvatar < Twitter
      def user_info_mapping
        {
          avatar: "avatar",
          # ...
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(I haven't tried running this code, so the details might be a little off, but from reading the Sorcery source code this looks like the right direction.)